# How is accomplished password match between AD FS and StoreDB?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, adfs

just trying to get my head around password synchronisation. In Windows Azure Active Directory Store DB the password will be matched to AD FS by which method? I getting a lot of reading about tokens and protocols, but is there anything else I have to aware of?
It's just general before I can dive deeper in synchronisation.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's done via AAD Connect. If you tick "password sync.", the password in AD (which is already hashed) is hashed again and propagated up to AAD.

Note that AAD doesn't use a "traditional DB". It uses a graph structure.